# careers live preview and help side note positioned over resized edit box

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

In Chrome, if I resize a textarea the live preview and help side note appear over it:

[live preview textbox overlap http://img402.imageshack.us/img402/9369/careerslivepreview.png](http://img402.imageshack.us/img402/9369/careerslivepreview.png)